# if statement ignores bool value in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I must doing something wrong, because inside the `NSDictionary` the values are 1 or 0 and it always prints `"locked"`...

```
let object: NSDictionary = self.collectionObjects?.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary
if let locked = (object.objectForKey("locked") as? NSNumber)?.boolValue {
    println("locked")
} else {
    println("open")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your not testing anything there

Try,

```
let object: NSDictionary = self.collectionObjects?.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary
let locked = (object.objectForKey("locked") as? NSNumber)?.boolValue
if locked == true
{  
    println("locked")
}
else
{
    println("open")
}
```

Comment: that shows an error: `Bound value in a conditional binding must be of Optional type` on `== `

Comment: Just because you are the first one that answered and helped me, I've accepted your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When you are doing:

```
if let locked = (object.objectForKey("locked") as? NSNumber)?.boolValue {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

The **if** statement is checking whether or not your `locked` variable has evaluated to a `nil` value. If it has a value then the `true` statement block will be executed; if it has `nil` then the `false` block (else statement) will be executed.

This is called [Optional Binding](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID333).

> You use optional binding to find out whether an optional contains a
>   value, and if so, to make that value available as a temporary constant
>   or variable. Optional binding can be used with if and while statements
>   to check for a value inside an optional, and to extract that value
>   into a constant or variable, as part of a single action.

As a result, if your variable does not evaluate to `nil` then you could use the `locked` variable inside the `if` block.

For example:

```
if let locked = (object.objectForKey("locked") as? NSNumber)?.boolValue {
    if locked {
        println("locked")
    } else {
        println("open")
    }
} else {
    println("locked is nil")
}
```

See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25828301/swift-if-let-optionals-how-is-it-evaluated) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is unwrapping the conditional value, not checking it, so what you need to do is:

1. Unwrap it
2. Test it

Handily, the if-let-where statement can do it for us in one line like this:

```
if let object = self.collectionObjects?.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? NSDictionary, locked = object.objectForKey("locked")?.boolValue where locked {
    // we have a value here and it happens to be true
} else {
    // this means we don't have a value
}
```

Include the first `let object` in the if statement too - you'll never know, it can be `null` and then it would unexpectedly crash.

Also, the compiler should be able to handle `object -> boolValue` directly, if not, add the `NSNumber` casting back.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend this

```
let object: NSDictionary = self.collectionObjects?.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary
if let locked = object.objectForKey("locked") as? NSNumber where locked.boolValue == true {
  print("locked")
}else {
  print("open")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are checking only the value is whether nil or not nil. As the value is not nil you are always getting output as "locked".

Try this

```
let object: NSDictionary = self.collectionObjects?.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary 
if let locked = (object.objectForKey("locked") as? NSNumber)?.boolValue { 
    If locked == true {
        println("locked")
    }
    else { 
        println("open") 
    }
}
```