# " if let " must be used only for optional ? (Swift)

Tags: swift

Question 1: if let  must be used only for optional

Question 2: If yes for question 1 , Does "if let " evaluate true or false or something ? Because we use this in a " if condition " and only way " if condition " works is to evaluate true or false. Here example :

```
var something:String? = " Hello "

if let makeSomethingNew = something {
    let final = makeSomethingNew + something
}
```

**let makeSomethingNew = something evaluates true here ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question 1**

`if let` is knowns as [optional binding](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html).

It only works on Optionals. The following code would generate an error:

```
var str = "Hello, playground"

if let x = str {
    print("success") // error: initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String'
}
```

Why? Because *if let* is only used for optionals, `String` is not an optional.

**Question2**

And yes it evaluates if the optional has been set ie has a value.

For more info see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25828301/how-is-swift-if-let-evaluated/38041086#38041086)

**Additional question**: Why are we doing such?

Because optionals are either set or not ( have a value or not). We want to only do something if they have a value. If they don't have a value, we don't want to do anything (we don't want to crash either).

You also use it to **unwrap** the optional.

```
var optionalString : String? = "hi"

if let unwraped = optionalString {
    print (unwraped) // hi | easier to work with
    print(optionalString) // Optional("hi") | not so easy to work with
}
```