# Checking variable in Swift

Tags: swift

In Swift you can't check variables directly like this:

```
if testValue {
    ...
}
```

However, you can check it by, in fact, reassigning it like this:

```
let testValue: String?

if let test = testValue {
    ...
}
```

Why so? What is the magic under the hood??

Comment: `if test = testValue {` it is not even a valid Swift syntax

Comment: you may mean `if let test = testValue {`

Comment: You **can** check `if testValue` if the variable is `Bool`.

Comment: You may want to look up “optional binding” in the Swift Language Reference.

Comment: So, from you answers (having various usability and adequacy level) i assume that it is related to types overall and has an intend to keep all opreations type-explicit. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is Swift IF LET evaluated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25828301/how-is-swift-if-let-evaluated)

Answer (score 1):

if `testValue` is a Bool then you **can** say:

```
if testValue {
  //Code
}
```

However, Swift is more strictly typed than C and other C-like languages.

In C, a pointer can be nil, which is zero, which is the same as false, so

```
if (aPointer) {}
```

is equivalent to

```
if (aPointer != nil)
```

However, Swift doesn't allow that. Pointer types can't be zero, `nil` is a special "no value" setting that is **not** the same as zero or false.

You have to explicitly say `if aPointer != nil` in Swift.

As others have pointed out, `if let` is something different, known as "optional binding". To explain that you'd need to understand Optionals.

In Swift, nil values are handled by a special wrapper known as an "Optional". Think of an `Optional` as a wrapped package that can either be empty or can contain an object.

An `Optional` either contains some value or it contains nil. To get at the value inside you have to "unwrap" the `Optional`.

There is a "force wrap" (`!`) expression that says "Trust me, I know this `Optional` can never be nil." If you use it and the `Optional` **does** contain nil, your program crashes. Thus I call it the "crash if nil" operator, and suggest you avoid it unless you really know what you're doing.

Then there is "if let" optional binding. In the following code:

```
var value: String?

if let testValue = value {
    //test value only exists inside these braces.
    print(value)
} else {
    //testValue is not defined here
    print("value is nil")
}
//testValue isn't defined here either.
```

The `if let` says "if the Optional variable `value` contains a non-nil value, remove the value from the Optional and put it into a non-Optional `let` constant called `testValue`, that will only be defined inside the braces that follow the `if` statement.

There are also other ways of dealing with Optionals like `guard` statements and the "nil coalescing operator" but I'll leave it to you to research those. I'm not going to cover every aspect of `Opionals` in a short forum post.

Answer (score 0):

Conditional binding `if let`/`for let`/`while let` is a special form that's baked into the language. The `let test = testValue` part isn't the same as the statement that it would usually be parsed as. It has special, different, meaning when prefixed with `if`/`for`/`while`.